# Cannot install Tensorflow in Debian

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, debian

I am trying to install Tensorflow using pyenv since the python 3.9.2 installed does not work with Tensorflow. I am running Debian OS 11.Everytime I run  " pip install Tensorflow " it shows

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Tensorflow.

I am using a 64bit OS with python 3.5.3 installed using Pyenv.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xP0e.jpg

Comment: You forgot to mention that you are using a Raspberry PI, which is a key difference on why you don't find any tensorflow packges in pip.

Comment: Sorry i am using Raspberry pi  4

Answer (score 1):

The process of installing tensor flow has changed over the years a little bit. A few years ago, they didn’t support versions of python greater than 3.6.4, causing users to downgrade their version of python. Now, there is something called tensorflow 2 which supports the higher versions of python. When you try to run the command `pip install tensorflow`, pip is trying to look for a version of tensorflow which is for the higher versions of python. Here are your two solutions:

You can install a version of tensorflow that corresponds to the version of python you have, so both are compatible. Here is the command: `pip install tensorflow==1.5` for CPU edition, and `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.5` for GPU edition. With the older versions, the libraries were different for your CPU and GPU.

Your alternative solution is to install a higher version of python. With py versions 3.7-3.10, they use tensorflow 2 which can be installed with `pip install tensorflow`. This library for newer versions comes with support for both CPU and GPU in one package.

Comment: I installed python 3.9.2. It still shows the same error. I couldnot install keras with the default python version (3.9.2) but when I used pyenv and installed 3.6.3 keras could be installed.

Comment: As dr. Snoopy said above, you are using a raspberry pi which is the reason why pip isn’t finding any tensorflow packages. I don’t recommend trying to use tensorflow on a computer with such little power, maybe there are other options out there that can help you with the project you are trying to make.

Comment: I am doing this project - https://towardsdatascience.com/deeppicar-part-3-d648b76fc0be which he used raspberry pi 3b+. Also do intel neural computing stick need tensorflow ?